# Replacing single quote with double quotes in PL-SQL dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below query:

```
select ''|| CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
         || 'INSERT into ' || v_TableName || '(' || v_Columns || ')' || CHR(10) 
         || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR(v_Values,1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Values))-1) || ')' from dual;
```

where upon executing i get:

v_TableName ='tblRecHistCalc',

v_Columns='average_eps,company_id,rec_code,rec_date'

v_Values='3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019','

So the query becomes:

```
select ''|| CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
         || 'INSERT into ' || 'tblRecHistCalc' || '(' || 'average_eps,company_id,rec_code,rec_date' || ')' || CHR(10) 
         || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR('3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019',',1, LENGTH(RTRIM('3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019','))-1) || ')' from dual;
```

But i am unable to execute the above query as there are single quotes in 'B' and '20-Mar-2019' which is stopping the query to execute succesfully.

I tried changing it to below:

```
select ''|| CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
         || 'INSERT into ' || 'tblRecHistCalc' || '(' ||'average_eps,company_id,rec_code,rec_date' || ')' || CHR(10) 
         || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR(Replace('3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019',',''','''''),1, LENGTH(RTRIM('3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019','))-1) || ')' from dual;
```

But still the query does not execute successfully.

How can i achieve this?

EDIT:

As asked by *Alex Poole*,
The variables are declared as follows:

v_TableName NVARCHAR2(50);

v_Columns Nvarchar2(4000);

v_Values Nvarchar2(4000);

v_Count NUMBER(10);

v_SQL Nvarchar2(4000):= '';

And the below shows how the three variables are getting populated:

```
WHILE (v_Count > 0) 
LOOP 
v_Columns := ''; 
v_Values := ''; 

-- Gets 1 table name at a time 
SELECT TableName INTO v_TableName  
FROM ( 
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY TableName) as Rowcnt, TableName  
        FROM 
        --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL STARTS
        (

            SELECT D.TableName, D.ColumnName, D.Val
            FROM 

            --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations STARTS
            (         
                SELECT ID, TableName, ColumnName, Val  
                FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
                JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
                WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
                AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
                AND  (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

                UNION 

                SELECT FieldID, TableName, ColumnName, Val 
                FROM tblTemplates_Fields_OtherDestinations OD 
                JOIN  
                ( 
                    SELECT ID, Val 
                    FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
                    JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
                    WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
                    AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
                    AND    (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

                ) UsedIDs 
                ON OD.FieldID = UsedIDs.ID


            ) D
            --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations ENDS

            JOIN USER_TAB_COLS C  ON upper(D.TableName) = upper(C.TABLE_NAME) AND upper(D.ColumnName) = upper(C.COLUMN_NAME)
            WHERE (v_UpdateComp = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblComp') 
            AND (v_UpdateCompInd = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblCompInd') 
            ORDER BY D.TableName, D.ColumnName
        )

        --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL ENDS
         GROUP BY TableName 
    ) DistinctTableNames 
WHERE Rowcnt = v_Count; 



-- Get lists of all columns  for current table 
 Select  LISTAGG( ColumnName, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) 
          into v_Columns
 FROM 
 --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL STARTS
  (

        SELECT D.TableName, D.ColumnName, D.Val
        FROM 

        --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations STARTS
        (         
            SELECT ID, TableName, ColumnName, Val  
            FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
            JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
            WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
            AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
            AND  (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

            UNION 

            SELECT FieldID, TableName, ColumnName, Val 
            FROM tblTemplates_Fields_OtherDestinations OD 
            JOIN  
            ( 
                SELECT ID, Val 
                FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
                JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
                WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
                AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
                AND    (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

            ) UsedIDs 
            ON OD.FieldID = UsedIDs.ID


        ) D
        --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations ENDS

        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS C  ON upper(D.TableName) = upper(C.TABLE_NAME) AND upper(D.ColumnName) = upper(C.COLUMN_NAME)
        WHERE (v_UpdateComp = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblComp') 
        AND (v_UpdateCompInd = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblCompInd') 
        ORDER BY D.TableName, D.ColumnName
   )

   --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL ENDS

WHERE TableName = v_TableName ;

-- Get lists of all  values for current table 

Select   LISTAGG(
            CASE ISNUMERIC(Val) 
                WHEN 1 THEN Val 
                WHEN 0 THEN '''' || REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Val)), '''','''''') || '''' 
            END
            || ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) 
            into v_Values
 FROM 
 --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL STARTS
  (

        SELECT D.TableName, D.ColumnName, D.Val
        FROM 

        --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations STARTS
        (         
            SELECT ID, TableName, ColumnName, Val  
            FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
            JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
            WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
            AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
            AND  (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

            UNION 

            SELECT FieldID, TableName, ColumnName, Val 
            FROM tblTemplates_Fields_OtherDestinations OD 
            JOIN  
            ( 
                SELECT ID, Val 
                FROM tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw OO  
                JOIN tblTemplates_Fields F ON OO.OtherObjectsField = F.FieldName 
                WHERE TemplateType IN ('All','ALL', v_TemplateType) 
                AND OO.Val IS NOT NULL 
                AND    (TemplateVersion = p_TemplateVersion or (TemplateVersion is null and p_TemplateVersion <> 'V8')) 

            ) UsedIDs 
            ON OD.FieldID = UsedIDs.ID


        ) D
        --#tmp_Templates_Load_Destinations ENDS

        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS C  ON upper(D.TableName) = upper(C.TABLE_NAME) AND upper(D.ColumnName) = upper(C.COLUMN_NAME)
        WHERE (v_UpdateComp = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblComp') 
        AND (v_UpdateCompInd = 0 OR D.TableName <> 'tblCompInd') 
        ORDER BY D.TableName, D.ColumnName
   )

   --#tmp_Templates_Load_InsertSQL ENDS

WHERE TableName = v_TableName ;



-- Build Insert and append to v_SQL variable 
v_SQL:= v_SQL || CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
        || 'INSERT into ' || v_TableName || '(' || SUBSTR(v_Columns, 1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Columns))) || ')' || CHR(10) 
        || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR(v_Values, 1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Values))-1) || ')' ;

v_Count := v_Count -1; 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_SQL;
end loop;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you are declaring and populating all those variables, and how you are generating and using the dynamic statement. How does your original code - with `v_Values` etc. referenced within it - become either of the other two statements, and how do you then try to execute that?

Comment: @AlexPoole : I edited the question.

Comment: With your latest edit, the way you build `v_sql` works the same as my answer; at least as long as that variable is null to start with. But your question shows a `select` - where has that gone? What error are you actually getting from this code? (A cut-down/simplified [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much easier to understand, run ourselves, and correct, incidentally- that's a lot of code of wade through... and we don't have your tables or data.)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't show how you're currently transforming one statement to the other - I suspect using dynamic SQL you don't need - but you can do it like this:

```
declare
  v_TableName varchar2(30) := 'tblRecHistCalc';
  v_Columns varchar2(80) := 'average_eps,company_id,rec_code,rec_date';
  v_Values varchar2(80) := q'[3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019',]';

  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  select ''|| CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
           || 'INSERT into ' || v_TableName || '(' || v_Columns || ')' || CHR(10) 
           || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR(v_Values,1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Values))-1) || ')'
  into v_sql
  from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_query);

end;
/
```

or with assignment instead of a select against the dual table:

```
  v_sql := CHR(10) || CHR(10)  
           || 'INSERT into ' || v_TableName || '(' || v_Columns || ')' || CHR(10) 
           || 'VALUES (' || SUBSTR(v_Values,1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Values))-1) || ')';
```

either of which generates:

```
INSERT into tblRecHistCalc(average_eps,company_id,rec_code,rec_date)
VALUES (3.3887524216711,25597,'B','20-Mar-2019')


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

`'20-Mar-2019'` is still just a string, so you're relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings - if you're executing that insert immediately then they will at least match, but you'll lose the time portion of any values (with this model; worse effects are possible) and it would be better to use explicit conversions to and from a string value.

I'm also unclear from your code - not that I've examined it in too much detail - how `v_Values` ends up with a trailing comma; but you could `trim()` that off too instead of using `substr()`.